# How do i put al the views in a scrollable view without losing the constrain layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I've seen mutiple examples on Google but I still can't get a scrollview without losing my current constraint layout. I want put all the textviews(except first one), textedits and buttons in a scrollview. Can someone explain or show how to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView/>

<EditText/>

<EditText/>

<EditText/>

<EditText/>

<EditText />

<EditText/>

<EditText/>

<EditText/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<TextView/>

<Button/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Doe & welcome to StackOverFlow. My approach to do that is to use RelativeLayout as a main container instead of ConstraintLayout. (WHY?)

Because it makes is easy to put a TextView above a ScrollView, and other TextViews & EditTexts inside!

This is how I do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Example of the first TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewExample"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Example of the other TextViews"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView550" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Example of the other TextViews"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView540" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thx, I used your code, but changed the relative layout to a constraint and inverted the position of the scrollview and layout as it didn't display my layout as meant. And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your problem
Is this not suits for you?

```
<LinearLayout>

<TextView/>

<ScrollView>
<ConstraintLayout>

<EditText/>
<EditText/>
<EditText/>
<EditText/>   
<EditText />    
<EditText/>    
<EditText/>    
<EditText/>    
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>   
<TextView/>    
<TextView/>    
<Button/>

</ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView` like:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    ... yours views ...

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If you want to keep some views outside of scroll, simply wrap the `ScrollView` into an other `ViewGroup` like `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.